# Иллюзия 3D в 2D игре

Tags: html5, canvas, разработка-игр, 3d, 2d

Привет, пилю игру на html5. Есть такая сцена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально она была собрана в редакторе тайлов, но теперь я понял что тайлы в данном cлучае не подходят т.к. есть такие сложности: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут персонаж должен как-то и ходить по тайлу, и не ходить. Так как и стена и пол на одном тайле.

И я не могу понять как сделать чтобы персонаж был на половину в картике, там где стены, мы части персонажа видеть не должны. То есть вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос собственно: с помощью какой техники реализовать рендеринг этой карты, как все это оживить, по каким запросам гуглить ?**

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь !)

Comment: Нужно маску столкновения у стены сделать равной воображаемому основанию стены, а глубину отрисовки меньше, чем у персонажей.

Comment: Вы говорите про WebGL я правильно понимаю ?

Comment: Нет, я говорю об общепринятых концепциях разработки игр. Вебом не занимаюсь, детали реализации — другой вопрос.

Comment: Лучше всего будет разбить сцену на слои, чтобы пол был на нижнем слое, игрок на уровень выше, а стены еще выше. Тогда они будут закрывать игрока, когда он находится за ними. Но фронтальные стены (те, которые дальше игрока) чтобы были на уровне где и пол. Это самое универсальное решение

Answer (score 1):

### Стены между тайлами

Каждому тайлу можно задать флагами в какие стороны с него возможно перемещение. Например, в вашем примере, у 2 тайлов должны стоять флаги, что движение с левого тайла вправо и с правого влево - невозможно.

### Стены зданий

Тайлам можно задать, на какой плоскости они находятся - под персонажем (большинство) или над персонажем. В вашем примере стенки должны быть над персонажем. Сделать это можно как флагами и расчетом на CPU, так и отрисовывая всю сцену на GPU с использованием Z-buffer. Выбор тут за вами.

Если рост персонажа больше 1 тайла, то если он стоит у стенки спереди, надо проверять, чтобы его голова не оказалась под стенкой.